# Oracle Query to get all the users with roles & skills

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Below are my tables. There are 4 tables contains user, roles , High level roles & Roles with skills. I want to get all the users who have roles & detail skills.
Below is the sample of output expected. I am in need for a query to get below mentioned output. Thanks for your help.

Table  T1

```
T1_ID     Name
101       Peter
102       Kevin 
103       Ross 
104       Smith
```

Table  T2

```
T2_ID          Role
201             Admin
202             Programmer
203             Tester
204             Analyst
```

Table  T3

```
T3_ID        T1_ID            T2_ID
301          101               201
302          102               202
303          102               204
304          104               202
305          104               203
```

Table T4

```
T4_ID      T1_ID       T2_ID    Skill
401         102        202      Java
402         102        202      Spring
403         102        204      Microsoft
404         104        202      c++
405         104        203      website
```

I want output (All the user  who have roles & skills  from T3 & T4).

```
T1_ID        user_name          Role                      skill
101          Peter              Admin          
102         Kevin              Programmer                 Java
102         Kevin              Programmer                 Spring
102         Kevin              Analyst                    Microsoft
104         Smith              Programmer                 C++
104         Smith              Tester                     Website
```

Comment: You're more likely to get better answers if you're able to demonstrate that you have [tried something yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and are not just asking other users to do your coding for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to do a series of joins to link all the tables up together.off the top of my head, something like the following might work:

```
select t1.*, T2.Role, T4.Skill from T1
left join T3 on T3.T1_ID = T1.T1_ID
left join T2 on T2.T2_ID = T3.T2_ID
left join T4 on T4.T1_ID = T1.T1_ID and T4.T2_ID = T2.T2_ID 
order by 1
```

have a look at this page for a simple example of the different types of joins https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=595030

--Edit--

Updated query to work, it will produce the above table but also include Ross, without any role or skill.

```
T1_ID        user_name          Role                      skill
103          Ross
```

If you don't want people to appear that have no role, add the following line before the 'order by 1' line.

```
where T2.Role is not null
```

Comment: `where T2.Role != ''` is invalid. For legacy reasons Oracle treats the empty string as null. As you cannot use an equality operator on null this should be where `T2.Role is not null` (though I don't believe you need this at all).

Comment: Your welcome @Shri ... if the solution works don't forget to click the tick on the left of the answer to mark it as accepted ;-)